# Is it possible to set user defined session/connection flag for use in trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Consider a trigger that sets an id-column to an Oracle-sequence (next-)value on-insert. Now I want to extend it with some extra debugging actions. But they should be only active for certain connection/sessions (i.e. debugging ones).

Pseudo-Code on client side:

- Open connection to oracle database
- set mydebugflag=yes for that connection only
- insert some stuff
- close connection

Pseudo-Code on server-side (inside the trigger):

- set id = someseq.next_val
- if mydebugflag=yes then { do_some_extra_sanity_checks(); diagnostics();}
- else: finished

How to implement such logic for an Oracle database?

Which Oracle features should I use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

One is to create a package, create a package global variable (which will have session scope) in the package, and then have your client set the package variable and your trigger read it.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_debug_mode
AS
  PROCEDURE set_debug_mode( p_debug_mode IN NUMBER );
  FUNCTION  get_debug_mode
    RETURN  NUMBER;

  DEBUG_MODE_ON  constant number := 1;
  DEBUG_MODE_OFF constant number := 2;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_debug_mode
AS
  g_debug_mode NUMBER := DEBUG_MODE_ON;
  PROCEDURE set_debug_mode( p_debug_mode IN NUMBER )
  AS
  BEGIN
    g_debug_mode := p_debug_mode;
  END;
  FUNCTION get_debug_mode
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN g_debug_mode;
  END;
END;
```

The client calls `pkg_debug_mode.set_debug_mode` to set the debug mode and the trigger calls `pkg_debug_mode.get_debug_mode` to determine the current debug mode for the session.

```
create or replace context my_ctx using pkg_debug_mode;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_debug_mode
AS
  PROCEDURE set_debug_mode( p_debug_mode IN NUMBER )
  AS
  BEGIN
    dbms_session.set_context( 'MY_CTX', 'DEBUG_MODE', p_debug_mode );
  END;
  FUNCTION get_debug_mode
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN SYS_CONTEXT( 'MY_CTX', 'DEBUG_MODE' );
  END;
END;
```

Your trigger can either call the `get_debug_mode` function or it can directly reference the context by putting the `SYS_CONTEXT` call in the trigger.

Comment: Ok, you show two methods. The 2nd one uses a user defined context. One question regarding the package local variable - does 'session scope' mean that two clients which connect via the same user have their own package-local-variable-instances? I.e. that writing a value in connection A does not overwrite the value in connection B? (where A and B are opened by the same user)

Comment: @maxschlepzig - A package variable is scoped to the session.  If there are two physical database connections, that would mean that there are two sessions (whether it is the same user or not is not relevant).  If we're talking about a three-tier applications where multiple application sessions are using a small pool of physical database connections, two different users may well end up sharing the same session in which case your connection pool would need to clean up any session state when a connection is logically closed.